# Join two table with different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table that I want to combine without FULL OUTER JOIN as it not work in h2 db. I have to create select sql query:I have tried much with UNION too but I think it will not be possible with UNION.

**Table 1**

```
id     c_id       s_id           p_date
---------------------------------------------
1       1          1              2020-10-10
2       1          1              2020-10-11
3       2          1              2020-10-11
4       2          2              2020-10-12
```

**Table 2**

```
id     c_id       s_id           s_date
---------------------------------------------
1       1          1              2020-10-15
2       1          2              2020-10-16
3       2          2              2020-10-17
4       2          2              2020-10-17
```

I am expecting below result:

```
    c_id       s_id      p_date        s_date
    -------------------------------------------------
    1          1        2020-10-10      2020-10-15
    1          1        2020-10-11         -
    1          2            -           2020-10-16
    2          1        2020-10-11         -
    2          2        2020-10-12      2020-10-17
    2          2            -           2020-10-17
```

Please help to get this result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` like this:

```
select t1.c_id, t1.s_id, t1.p_date, t2.s_date
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.c_id = t2.c_id and t1.s_id = t2.s_id
union all
select t2.c_id, t2.s_id, t1.p_date, t2.s_date
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.c_id = t2.c_id and t1.s_id = t2.s_id
where t1.c_id is null;
```

The first subquery gets all the rows where there are matches between the two tables plus rows where `table2` has no match for `table1`.

The second subquery gets the additional rows from `table2` that have no match in `table1`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=381506f1189fa183b868fa1b69f10268) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: No. It is not generating desired result not even close the result. Only 3 row is getting with repeated s_date.

Comment: @rahul . . . .Then you are doing something wrong, because it returns the correct results when I run the code.  I've included a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I ran exactly same query as you posted it. but my expected result is little different.. I have tried it all.

Comment: @Rahul . . . Look at the db<>fiddle.  The query is running there.